# Lotus notes Mail sent with Macro cannot be seen on smartphones

Tags: excel, lotus-notes, smartphone, vba

I have a macro that sends emails via Lotus Notes to certain people. Everything works well, except for one thing: smart phones do not receive these mails (which is a must), even though on laptops the mails are received.

Any idea what the cause could be?

Comment: Can you show us your VBA code?

Comment: Also, you need to say what happens when a recipient has both a smartphone and a regular PC (or Mac) client. Does the recipient see the email on their PC but not on their phone?

Answer (score 0):

"Smart phones do not receive these mails (which is a must), even though on laptops the mails are received":

Check the following:

- Are you sending an attachment
- Is the attachment ending in `xlsm` or `xlsb`?
- Can you simply try to send it to a standard google or yahoo mail and see whether you receive it?

If the answer of all 3 above is yes, then you should check the security settings of the phone's mail - most probably they are high, thus `xlsm` and `xlsb` files are considered to be a virus.
To go around it, consider zipping the `xlsm` or `xlsb` files. [How to ZIP a file with VBA](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section7.htm).